# Joining 2 tables with multile rows

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

I have two Tables.

```
Main 
Id Name
1  abc
2  efg

Image
MainId ImagePath
1        ..//
1        ..//
2        ..//
1        ..//
2        ..//
```

I need to combine these two tables to get a single row with MainId as the key. It could link with any random Image from the Image table.

But currently when I am joining, its joining  and displaying all the rows from the Image table.

```
SELECT a.Id,b.ImagePath FROM Main a, Image b  WHERE a.Id=b.MainId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of picking a random Image would be ....

```
Select m.ID , I.ImagePath
FROM Main m 
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ImagePath
              FROM Image
              WHERE MainId = m.ID
              ORDER BY NEWID()
              ) I(ImagePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated query:

```
SELECT t.id,
       (SELECT s.ImagePath FROM Image s
        WHERE t.id = s.MainId
        LIMIT 1) as imagePath
FROM Main t
```

Or just join to a derived tables containing one `imagePath` per `ID` :

```
SELECT t.id,s.ImagePath
FROM Main t
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.MainId,max(s.ImagePath) as max_im
           FROM Image s
           GROUP BY s.MainId) tt
 ON(t.id = tt.max_un)
```

Comment: Im afraid this is not a Random selection of an Image.

Comment: Actually , " It could link with any random Image" means that It doesn't have to be a random value - he doesn't care which one.

Comment: ... "Any random" could me `MAX/MIN` or any other value, if he'd ask to choose randomly, that's a whole different thing:) Or maybe I misunderstood him.

Comment: Exactly ..... a random value is `MIN` or `MAX` but always a `MAX` value is not random it is `MAX` :)

Comment: Yea I understand what you are saying, but you're not understanding me. I understand the question as "I don't care what value I'll get" , so even if it's not random, it doesn't matter.